# Updating CListView maintaining event handlers

Tags: php, ajax, listview, yii

I am using Yii framework, and make an extensive use of CListViews. However i am continously facing a problem which i cant solve:

This is my CListView

```
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'viewData'=>array('sent'=>$sent),
            'dataProvider'=>$dp,
            'pager' => array(
                            'prevPageLabel'=>'< Prev.',
                            'nextPageLabel'=>'Next>',
                            'header'=>'Pagina: ',
                            'pageSize'=>5,),
            'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}", 
            'itemView'=>'_messageView',
            'emptyText'=>'Empty inbox',
            'enablePagination'=>true,
            'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:function(id) {alert("after");}',
            'id'=>'listMessages',
        ));
```

And i have a JS method which updates the list the following way:

```
function sent_view(){
$.fn.yiiListView.update('listMessages',
        {data:'type=sent', url:'view?sort=timestamp&ajax=listMessages'});
}
```

After this function is called, all events that were tied up to each item of the CListView is no longer there. I tried adding the next piece of code so as to attach the handlers again, however it doesn't work. It doesn't even get to display an alert if i add it right after the $.fn.yiiListView.update line of code.

```
$(".individualMessage").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    $(this).css("background",'url(/../images/messages/background.png)');
});
```

Has someone encountered a similar problem? thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using "delegate" or "live" jQuery construct? http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: You were right, it was the live function! I ws just not using it correctly. Thanks both!! (@ldg and @sadaf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery's "live" function e.g.

```
$(".individualMessage").live("mouseover",function(){
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    $(this).css("background",'url(/../images/messages/background.png)');
});
```

Comment: Note jQuery.live with hover events is going to slow down a large page (as I found out the hard way), and technically .live is depreciated in jQuery 1.7. It'll work as a kludge, but it's not ideal.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.